# how to fix copy in prism.js when i add ngAfterViewChecked

Tags: angular, typescript, copy, prismjs

I tried to copy the code but doesn't work. I'm using prism.js but when i use ngAfterViewChecked the copy does'nt work anymore.

when I add in my component :

```
public ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
     if (!this.highlighted) {
     this.highlightService.highlightAll();
     this.highlighted=true;
     }
  }
```

the copy doesn't work any more . Any solution please?

Comment: what do you mean the copy doesn't work anymore? Are you unable to copy the code from the highlighted code?

Comment: i mean to copy the code from the highlighted code by clicking the toolbar Copy

like in this link [link](https://auralinna.blog/post/2017/code-syntax-highlighting-with-angular-and-prismjs)

Comment: Could you try recreating your issue on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/)

Comment: i creat the issue on StackBlitz , the copy  worked but  highlighting code no, i don't understand the problem in my local